# Can Confluent S3SourceConnector read a CSV file from S3 bucket?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, s3-kafka-connector

Do we have any Confluent Kafka in-build Connector to read the data from from S3 bucket from a CSV file.

Can S3SourceConnector do the job for me?

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
format.class=io.confluent.connect.s3.format.string.StringFormat
```

This should read lines from files.

You'd be better suited to use something else to actually parse the data, such as SparkSQL